How to use standardscaler() for the predict() function for a single row having multiple columns?
I am trying to build a house price prediction system. Data has outliers and is non-gaussian and for target feature y, log transform is used. I have used StandardScaler() to fit for my model before doing one-hot encoding. The code looks like this:
numerical_features = df4[['bhk', 'area', 'price_lakhs', 'price_per_sqft']]
categorical_features = df4.select_dtypes(include=['object'])

scaler = StandardScaler()
standardized_features = scaler.fit_transform(numerical_features)

std_df4 = pd.DataFrame(standardized_features, columns=numerical_features.columns)
std_df4.head()

Now for predicting for new values, I used predict_price() function. I have a hard time understanding how to do it the same as the upper block of code. I separated numerical and categorical values. I can't do the same below. This code works wrongly and I think the one hot encoded values from columns x[3:] also might have been scaled which is not how upper code works. Any Regressor model (clf.predict() in below code) I use gives same answers for different values of input to predict() below.
def predict_price(bhk, area, price_per_sqft, type, region):    
    
    house_type_loc_index = np.where(X.columns == 'type_' + type)[0][0]
    print(house_type_loc_index)
    
    region_loc_index = np.where(X.columns == 'region_' + region)[0][0]
    print(region_loc_index)

    x = np.zeros(len(X.columns))
    x[0] = bhk
    x[1] = area
    x[2] = price_per_sqft
    
    if house_type_loc_index >= 0:
        x[house_type_loc_index] = 1
        
    if region_loc_index >= 0:
        x[region_loc_index] = 1
    
    columns = X.columns
    x = x.reshape(1, -len(columns))

    scaler = StandardScaler()
    standardized_features = scaler.fit_transform(x)
    data = pd.DataFrame(standardized_features, columns = columns)
    
    print(data)
    
    ans = clf.predict(data)[0]
    return exp(ans)

I was expecting the model to be able to predict values based on the inputs I gave to the predict function. The predict function is called as below.
predict_price(bhk = 2, area = 2000, price_per_sqft = 35, type = 'Apartment', region = 'Airoli')

The answer I got is: 42.610385322858455
predict_price(bhk = 3, area = 600, price_per_sqft = 70, type = 'Villa', region = 'Vashi')

The answer I got is: 42.610385322858455
I checked further more and every value it receives is 0 for both above lines of predict_price(). That's why maybe I strongly think I am using standardScaler() wrongly in predict().
bhk  area  price_per_sqft  type_Apartment  type_Independent House  \
0  0.0   0.0             0.0             0.0                     0.0   

   type_Penthouse  type_Studio Apartment  type_Villa  region_Agripada  \
0             0.0                    0.0         0.0              0.0   

   region_Airoli  ...  region_Vasai  region_Vashi  region_Vikhroli  \
0            0.0  ...           0.0           0.0              0.0   

   region_Ville Parle East  region_Ville Parle West  region_Virar  \
0                      0.0                      0.0           0.0   

   region_Virar West  region_Wadala  region_Worli  region_other  
0                0.0            0.0           0.0           0.0  

